# EKReminder's lastModifiedDate property doesn't work?

Tags: ios, eventkit

I'm integrating my app with EventKit, and listening for EKEventStoreChangedNotifications. When one comes in, I'd like to see which reminders have changed in some way since the last update. I had hoped I could just use the `lastModifiedDate` property, but it doesn't seem to change -- it's always the same as the creation date, even for reminders that I know I've updated on another device.

Any idea what's going on and if there's a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Where you able to reliably get a modification date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ran into this bug as well.

We found out that *lastModifiedDateworks* when:

The event is created and modified only by the Desktop or Web Calendar Interface. When you change it on your iPhone, *lastModifiedDate* won't be updated by Desktop/Web any longer.

- Create event on Desktop -> *lastModifiedDate* is set
- Check event on iPad -> *lastModifiedDate* correct
- Modify event on Desktop and check event on iPad -> *lastModifiedDate* is updated
- Modify event on iPad and check event on Desktop -> *lastModifiedDate* is updated
- Modify event on Desktop and check event on iPad -> *lastModifiedDate* is NOT updated

OR

Desktop and Web Interface are not used. Tested with iPad Calendar App, GoogleMail and Exchange. Events can be modified on both ends of synchronisation.

Comment: It seems to be fixed with iOS 8.